# Convert Western Saddle to Regular Saddle?

Tags: saddle

I have a Sun adult trike with a western saddle.  That's the kind of saddle that you plunk your whole bum on, instead of a standard bike saddle that you straddle and just your sit bones contact.
[image: Saddle and U support bar]

This trike currently has the 19" U-shaped support bar and whatever the standard seatpost is (7/8" x ?).  This makes for a very low saddle height, and has that big honking saddle.  I'd like to replace this configuration with something higher up and a standard saddle if possible.  I know about the 21" support bar, and longer seat posts, but this bike does not have reasonable seat stays, so no way to just go to a standard seatpost/clamp arrangement (I think).

[image: The barely-existent seat tube stays.]

So, the question is, does anyone have thoughts, or better, has seen a product, that would let me mount a regular saddle on this support bar/weak seatpost combination?  I can get a longer support bar, and longer seatpost.  I can change the angle of the support bar, though not the seatpost.  I could weld on better seatstays, but with a 7/8" post, it probably still wouldn't be strong enough without something like the support bar.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like there might be welding in your bike's future.  A competent welder might be able to attach some better seat stays that terminate below the clamp.  Then you'd use a normal saddle on a normal seat post.

BUT there will be a lot of unsupported seat tube poking up.  As a tall rider, I have over-extended seatposts leading to bent seatposts and cracked frames.

---

Your other option is to get your welder to make a bridge between the existing seatpost and the existing stays, and then mount a normal saddle on that using an old-school saddle clamp but rotated down.

The risk here is the saddle will fall sideways if the bridge tube is round, so perhaps your metalworker can find some half-inch box section and mangle the bike clamp so it goes around a square profile.

Edit:
Here's a spin bike with something vaguely similar.  The seatpost can adjust up/down, and the horizontal box section sits in a channel, and can't move sideways.  It can move fore-aft if the hold-down bolt is released.  On top of that is a short vertical round tube, where a normal seat clamp fits.

[image: Own work]

[image: Also own work]

Comment: Ooh, that second part.  Forgot about the funky posts for spinning bikes.  Our fitness center has something like that.  OTOH, that led me to this page: [link](http://www.bicycleseats.org/exercise-seat-adaptor-choos.htm).  Still not quite right, but that gives me another idea.  What about using a longer 7/8" seatpost, and the longer support bar, but then, instead of the wide bum saddle, mount the regular saddle to the support bar with two small U-bolts or one wider, more square U-bolt?  The seat rails are perpendicular to the support bar.

Comment: @user3224303 good thinking - you'll either need to measure carefully or think how to include some kind of adjustment.

Comment: Yeah!  That's a lot like the one I spotted after you mentioned it.  I like that one though, I've never seen suspension on a spinning bike before!  It will take a bit of trial and error, because you're right, it will need to be adjustable a bit.  Thanks!  I'll post back after I've tried the u-bolt concept.